# Wait Until Condition become true

Tags: java

I got three classes in, which are TCPClient.java, TCPProtocol.java, TCPServer.java .

*Update, i paste my full TCPServer.java as well

first, user will input the text in TCPProtocol GUI Window (by using JTextarea), and click button "Send". TCPClient will get the input from TCPProtocol if user click "send", and last will send to TCPServer. So the problem is, my TCPClient never get the input from TCPProtocol.

TCPServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //TCP component
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    int port = 8081;
    TCPProtocol nis = new TCPProtocol();//create an object to call method in protocol class

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + " :Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("TCP Session established.");
        nis.frame.setVisible(true);
        nis.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        System.out.println();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + " :Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine, outputLine;
    outputLine = nis.processAnswer(null);//get Learn Learn English line
    out.println(outputLine);//and send the line out to client
    nis.Jservertxt.setText(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         outputLine = nis.processAnswer(inputLine);
         out.println(outputLine);
         nis.Jservertxt.setText(outputLine);
         if (outputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("Don't miss me! Bye Bye!"))
            break;
         else if (outputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("Thank For Your Guessing. Have a Nice Day =)"))
            break;
    }

    //End connection
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
    nis.frame.setVisible(false);
    if (!clientSocket.isClosed())
        clientSocket.close();
        nis.frame.setVisible(false);
    if (!serverSocket.isClosed())
        serverSocket.close();
        nis.frame.setVisible(false);

    System.out.println("TCP session closed.");
}
}
```

Here is my code for TCPProtocol.java

```
public volatile boolean getPressed;
Jsend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String Data = Jusertxt.getText();
            Jusertxt.setText(null);
            System.out.println(Data);
            getPressed=true;
    }
    });
    }

    public boolean getPressed()
    {
        return getPressed;
    }
```

i din't paste the full code here because i just show the part where do got problem.

and here is my TCPClient Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient{

public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    //TCP component
    int port = 8081;
    String host = "localhost";
    Socket nisSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    TCPProtocol pro = new TCPProtocol();

    try {
        nisSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(nisSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nisSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + " :Don't know about " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + " :Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer, fromUser;

    while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        if (fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("Don't miss me! Bye Bye!"))
            break;
        if (fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("Thank For Your Guessing. Have a Nice Day =)"))
            break;

        if (pro.getPressed())
        {
            fromUser = pro.Jusertxt.getText();
            if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("\nClient: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                    }
        }
            System.out.println("fail liao");

    }
    System.out.println("try again");
    //End connection
    out.flush();
    out.close();        
    in.close(); 
    stdIn.close();

    //if (!nisSocket.isClosed())
        nisSocket.close();
    System.out.println("TCP session closed.");
}
}
```

So how can i only let the TCPClient.java process if only getPressed() method was true.

I try using volatile boolean variable but not working as well. Or should i use synchronized?

---

Solve after change to call GUI code from server to client

```
while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
        if (fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("Don't miss me! Bye Bye!"))
            break;
        if (fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("Thank For Your Guessing. Have a Nice Day =)"))
            break;

        pro.frame.setVisible(true);
        pro.frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        pro.Jservertxt.setText(fromServer);
        if(pro.getPressed()){
            fromUser = pro.getMessage();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                        System.out.println("\nClient: " + fromUser);
                        out.println(fromUser);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually is pro.getPressed(), return getPressed is a boolean variable is was declare, i forgot to put in, sorry

Comment: What is 'in'? What is 'out'? What is the observed behaviour? How do you know your TCPClient doesn't get the value from TCPProtocol? I'm asking because, if you are reading/writing on a regular Socket stream, your in.readLine() might be blocking your thread so that pro.getPressed() just doesn't execute unless your server sends a message. In this case you should probably consider having a dedicated thread that just reads data from server and using another thread to send fromUser to server.

Comment: "in" and "out" is inputStreamReader and outputStreamReader
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
out = new PrintWriter(nisSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nisSocket.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little example of a main thread (think of it as your TCPClient) that waits until user clicks button (think of this part as your TCPProtocol):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Object       lock    = new Object();
    private JTextArea   area    = new JTextArea();

    public Test() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton send = new JButton("send");
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notify();
                }

            }
        });
        add(area);
        add(send, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public String pullText() {
        String result = area.getText();
        area.setText("");
        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setSize(200, 200);
        t.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            synchronized (t.lock) {
                try {
                    t.lock.wait();
                    System.out.println(t.pullText());
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Maybe you can apply a similar approach to your system.

Warning: this is just a quick and dirty example to give you the idea, please double check it. In general you should be very careful when dealing with synchronization.

EDIT:
As a starting point you can modify your TCPProtocol class (the part you posted) like this:

```
public volatile boolean getPressed;

private Object lock = new Object(); // added lock for wait/notify coordination
private String Data; //changed scope to make it accessible in getMessage()

Jsend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        synchronized(lock){
            Data = Jusertxt.getText(); // no more a local variable, it's an instance attribute now, see declaration above
            Jusertxt.setText(null);
            System.out.println(Data);
            getPressed=true;
            lock.notify(); // notify client that user performed action
        }
    });
}

public boolean getPressed(){
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            lock.wait(); // wait for user to perform action...
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return getPressed; // ...then return value (I guess getPressed will always be true at this point)
}

public String getMessage(){ // call this in TCPClient instead of pro.Jusertxt.getText()
    return Data;
}
```

I added a lock object to enable wait/notify mechanism and applied that to your actionPerformed and getPressed methods.
I also changed the scope of Data variable and I added a public method to get its value (getMessage()). If you doublecheck your code you'll see that you will always get null from pro.Jusertxt.getText() in TCPClient.java because you set it to null in actionPerformed. So change pro.Jusertxt.getText() to pro.getMessage() in TCPClient.java.

```
// [...]
fromUser = pro.getMessage(); // used to be fromUser = pro.Jusertxt.getText();
// [...]
```

If you get this raw version to work then you can refine and refactor it to make it more clean and consistent. (for instance, I suspect you don't actually need getPressed variable as it's actually always true)

I confess I didn't test this code so you might have to fix or adjust it a little, but I hope it can clarify how I meant you could apply the code I posted to your system.

Hope it helps.

Good luck :-)

Comment: never use synchronization before, but i will try first. Thx u for the reply.

Comment: i try apply those code but not working, first time attempt using synchronization.

Comment: i tried, still not working. My TCPClient class , fromuser always can't get the value, i need stop the TCPClient thread before button was pressed. but i very appreciate your help, u taught a lot about synchronized in java. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I'm glad to know it was somehow helpful anyway. Good luck.

Comment: TCPClient class can't get the true value, i use
System.out.println("before press");
   
   if(pro.getPressed()){
    System.out.println("after press");
but the the system only print out "before press", "after press" is not print out although i click few time button "Jsend".

Comment: What about that System.out.println(Data); in the ActionListener? Do you see it in the console everytime you click? You might also want to add a couple of console logs just before and just after lock.wait() to check if it actually gets the notification.

Comment: ya, System.out.println(Data) have print out the output after button pressed. i trying now for after lock.wait().

Comment: my system completely done after i change to call GUI code from server to client, i don't know why but it really work, thank to u taught me how to work with synchronization in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while (!pro.getPressed()) {
                    System.out.println("still not true");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
System.out.println("getPressed is true");
```

Comment: i tired, but not working , will infinite loop in while (!pro.getPressed()){}, wont't to the line System.out.println("getPressed is true").

Comment: Then pro.getPressed() is not returning true in that case..!!
Even after a bit of time

Comment: ya, is there possible to stop the thread before "Jsend" button is click?

Comment: how it should be clicked, by user or programatically?

Comment: by user. My program suppose like once user finish key in input, click "send." TCPClient determine the input string if not null, the will use outputStream send the string to TCPServer.

Comment: Then you can add this code in jsend button onclicklistener. It should do the job.